# How do I debug a server PHP file that responds to jQuery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

I have the following JavaScript code that uses jQuery to POST form data to a PHP script called `sendContactFormEmail.php` on the server. When this PHP file runs fine, the browser displays the form submission results. However, when there is an error encountered when executing the PHP file, my browser displays nothing.

So how do I debug the PHP file? I need to send it post data and debug step by step but I'm not sure if I can do this from `Eclipse PHP`, or what tools I can use to debug this PHP file given that when I press the HTML form submit button nothing happens. Plus I need to debug with JSON being sent back and forth.

```
  if (formIsValid) {

    // retrieve input field values to be sent to server

    post_data = {
      'form_firstname'  : $('input[name=form_firstname]').val(), 
      'form_lastname'   : $('input[name=form_lastname]').val(), 
      'form_address'    : $('input[name=form_address]').val(), 
      'form_city'       : $('input[name=form_city]').val(), 
      'form_email'      : $('input[name=form_email]').val(), 
      'form_phone'      : $('input[name=form_phone]').val(), 
      'form_attachment' : $('input[name=form_attachment]').val(), 
      'form_message'    : $('textarea[name=form_message]').val(), 
    };

    // Ajax post data to server

    $.post('http://localhost/sendContactFormEmail.php', post_data, function(response) {  

      if (response.type == 'error') { // load json data from server and output message

        output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';

      } else {

        output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';

        // reset values in all form fields

        $(matchFormFields).val('');

      }

      // display an animation with the form submission results

      $(matchContactSubmitResult).hide().html(output).slideDown();

    }, 'json');

  }
```

Comment: Turn error reporting mode on in PHP and you'll see error messages in response

Comment: How do I do this? Is it not enabled by default? I am not seeing anything.

Comment: [This](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) might help you